# How to List the Hidden Apps You Can Uninstall in Windows?

Tags: bloatware, windows-10-apps

I know there are some hidden Microsoft apps and programs installed on my computer that aren't listed in App and Features. I would like to see if I can remove any of those as well. How do I find a list of them and then uninstall them?

Comment: I couldn't find a command that lists just the removable apps in one go. So I created this question and answer to help anyone looking for that answer in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to list all the installed apps and then filter them by just ones that are removable.

Right click the start button and click **Windows PowerShell (Admin)**.

Run the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object NonRemovable -eq $False | Select Name, PackageFullName
```

To uninstall one of them, type:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Package ""
```

Put the **PackageFullName** you retrieved from the first command inside the quotes "".

For example, on my system the PackageFullName of Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay is **Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_5.722.5052.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe**

To uninstall that I would run:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Package "Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_5.722.5052.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

Then when I list all the installed apps I can see that's gone but Microsoft has another similarly named app called Microsoft.Xbox**Game**Overlay so I uninstall that one as well.